# how to run app on xcode 7 simulator or device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

Before I updated from xcode 6 to 7, it was just right next to the run and stop button.

[image]

When i just click on the run button, it opens the iphone 5 simulator and from the simulator's menu, if i choose Hardware > device > iphone 6 plus, it's just completely black. If I try to run the app again, it just says that it's running on iphone 5 in Xcode.

[image]
[image]

How do I choose a different simulator?? or run on a physical device connected to the macbook?

This worked seamlessly on xcode6 with the use of the device dropdown menu beside the run and stop button. but now, that menu is gone.

Another question: I am unable to find ios9 simulator under preferences > downloads

[image]

Comment: In xCode 7 the simulators and devices drop down is still there.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, the device drop down is still there where it was used to be. Some people had written reviews in app store regarding some major bugs in Xcode 7.1, try updating your Xcode to 7.1.1(if you haven't already done that) which is now available(and post a screenshot of your Xcode please).

Comment: @AdeelMiraj I have edited my question and added screenshots.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT I've added screenshots now.

Comment: @JohannaCristineDy Which version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Xcode did not finish downloading. There was an error when I checked the update. I made it complete the download and xcode is okay again

Answer (score 0):

In one of the pre-versions of Xcode 7 I had the same issue. The problem was, that there were no simulators installed.

Go to Xcode -> Window -> Devices a window will pop up. Click on the plus button in the bottom left corner and configure some devices.

The device selector should show up in Xcode.

Comment: A list of devices can be seen. When I create a device. Like example "ipad Air" it just duplicated ipad Air in the list of devices =/

The drop down next to the run and stop buttons still did not appear.

Comment: I just saw, that you have updated Xcode. If it doesn't work after a restart of Xcode, I would delete it and download a fresh Xcode.

Comment: Turns out Xcode did not finish downloading. There was an error when I checked the update. I made it complete the download and xcode is okay again.